# configure database in flask

Tags: python, error-handling, flask

i am trying to configure database in flask but whenever i run the app than it give an error :- ImportError: No module named flask_peewee.db

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_peewee.db import Database

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

DATABASE = {
    'name': 'flasktesting.db',
    'engine': 'peewee.SqliteDatabase',
}
DEBUG = True
SECRET_KEY = 'ssshhhh'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

# instantiate the db wrapper
db = Database(app)



@app.route('/')
def Hello_World():

    return ' Are You Ready !!!!!!!!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you actually have `flask_peewee` installed? I ran your code and it worked perfectly with
flask_peewee being installed.
Try to run **`pip install flask_peewee`**.